# How to remove space after slash "/"

Tags: python, url, replace, whitespace

I am working with Python and I want to remove blank spaces in the URLs, in order to restore broken links.

This is a typical case I have to deal with.

> Text about something **https:// sr.a i/gMF**

The link has one blank space after the slash (/) which can be expected. But also it can have other blank spaces randomly distributed.

First, I want to fix if present the space after the slash (/)

```
.replace('/ ', '//')
```

**This code works fine to replace the blank space immediately after the slash, but is there a way to fix the link if the blank space occurs anywhere else WITHOUT removing all the white spaces since I need to preserve the meaning of the text?**

Comment: Why not simply remove all spaces?

Comment: Because I have other text, which I need to keep. Actually the reason I have to fix the link it's just to identify it, in order to delete it and keep the text only.

Comment: A single forward slash isn't treated in a special way.

Comment: You'll need to possibly use regular expressions to extract possible URLs which include spaces, and then remove all spaces like in [Nathan Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375551/1708751)'s answer. So for this you need to know what characters will be involved in the URLs you will be fixing since URL RegEx can be very complicated if you don't have any limitations.

Comment: You could see documentation about python regular expression module:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

Comment: The only thing I can know about these URLs is that they will always start with "https" or "http"

Comment: And how would you tell if the last part of: `https:// sr.a i/gMF/  the`, i.e. the `the` is part of the url or a regular word?

Comment: That's the problem

Comment: @Alex Well, that is not our call. It's hard to provide an answer that solves the problem if you're not sure about how such edge cases should be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regexp lib https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html with the following regexp

```
import re
text = re.sub(r"[/]\s", "/", text)
# r"" --> regexp in python
# [/] --> slash
# \s  --> blank
```

In this [online regexp editor](https://regex101.com/r/DNUfNx/1) you can play around an make the regexp more stable for certain corner cases

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`string.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function, and simply replace with white space with empty string.

```
>>> my_string = "https:// sr.a i/gMF"
>>> my_string
'https:// sr.a i/gMF'
>>> my_string.replace(" ","")
'https://sr.ai/gMF'
```

Comment: This would remove all the white spaces in the string, but I need to keep the other words separate and meaningful.

Comment: Is the link always going to be at the end of the line? For example, is there every going to be an instance where it may say "Words words words http:// some .link more words words words"?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it can be anywhere in the text

Comment: I'm thinking you may want to split the link part out, fix the white space in it, then rebuild your original string. But with words potentially occurring after the link, I don't know how you could determine when the link ends.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `.replace(' ','')` work.If there are many blank space, `import re` (regular expression)will help you.

Comment: Can you explain more how re (regular expression) would help to fix the problem?

Comment: sorry, I don't know you need to keep the other words separate. How about change the resulting string  again？